# Are group health insurance premiums cheaper than individual health insurance premiums?

Tags: united-states, small-business, health-insurance

I am self-employed and have one employee.  I am a health 35 year old, with healthy wife, and 1 child.  My employee is a 30 year old, also healthy.

Would group health insurance rates premiums be cheaper than individual rates, or be the same?

From my limited experience, they appear to be almost the same....but that was only getting a quote from one company.

Comment: I don't have any hard statistics, but I have seen small group policies that are actually _more_ expensive than their individual counterparts, albeit with wider networks.